# ffmpeg and iis smooth streaming

Tags: iis, ffmpeg, video-streaming, smooth-streaming, expression-encoder

I have a local iis instance with configured publishing point. The point is good I've tested it by Expression Encoder 4 Pro IIS smooth streaming feature.
But when I'm trying to stream to is using ffmpeg, Silverlight player can`t play my stream - just buffering action in process. Here is my ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="WebCam SC-13HDL11431N":audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -threads 2 -c:a libvo_aacenc -c:v libx264 -preset fast -b:v 64k -bufsize 64k -flags +global_header -f ismv http://localhost/lf.isml/Streams(lf)
```

Manifest file (http://localhost/lf.isml/manifest) is correct and available for Silverlight streaming but unfortunately player doesn't play my stream.
Any suggestion or help? Maybe I've forgot some parameter in command?

Comment: -pix_fmt yuv420p help?